# Permission denied when trying to transfer file with SCP from local machine to EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, scp

I am trying for the first time to transfer a file from my local machine to an EC2 instance.
I am managing to properly connect to the instance via ssh.

But when trying to transfer a file with scp, I get a permission denied.
I tried several things including making sure the destination folder was open to writing (CHMOD 777 of the destination folder).

Here is my verbose terminal output:

```
(finenv) ➜  deribit-snap git:(master) ✗ scp -v -i ~/.ssh/ec2-key-pair-mtlberri.pem ./snap-script.py ec2-user@ec2-18-216-175-218.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/deribit_script
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ec2-18-216-175-218.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com, user ec2-user, command scp -v -t /home/ec2-user/deribit_script
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-216-175-218.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Armellini1/.ssh/ec2-key-pair-mtlberri.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Armellini1/.ssh/ec2-key-pair-mtlberri.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-216-175-218.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8BODXGf6J+FunEc6LF6xDj+3vmf0E+SJLjHg6uUrYgc
debug1: Host 'ec2-18-216-175-218.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Armellini1/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Armellini1/.ssh/ec2-key-pair-mtlberri.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Armellini1/.ssh/ec2-key-pair-mtlberri.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ec2-18-216-175-218.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: The error is related to your keypairs. I suggest you start with the exact SSH command that successfully connect you to the instance, then change `ssh` into `scp`, then append the files to copy. If SSH works, then SCP should work, too (or at least get you past this particular problem).

Comment: Thanks John, I did reset everything and recreated the keys. It works now, unsure why it was blocking before. Thanks for your advice and pointing to the key. It helped me in the end.